# Change the default content type used to edit within a specific view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

Im not sure if this is just a pipe dream or not, pretty new to sharepoint but i have a number of views set up for my sharepoint online list. I was hoping that its possible to change the default content type used when clicking edit item based on which view im in?

Comment: Are you saying that you have more than one content types and each view is showing items created from unique content type?

Comment: Yes i have a number of different content types to reflect various stages in the process. The idea is that at each stage of the process, the user will click on the view theyre after to see the items waiting at that stage and add information to each item as it comes in.

Comment: Why do you want to change the default content type? Once an item is filled in with a content type, data will be visible from the respective content type edit form.

Comment: OK well a bit of background info, this system is for logging requests and asset info for mobile phones. the stages are the phone being requested, the order beign placed and the details being logged and the phone details being added once the phone arrives. say for example were at the stage of the phone arriving, the user will view all phones awaiting phone details and find the relevant request then click edit item. Id like it to default when clicking edit item to the phone details content type to so that the users dont need to switch and lead to confusion. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You cannot change the default content type setting of the list when editing an item from an view.

However you can do this to meet your requirement: You can add a content editor web part in the EditForm.aspx of the list and add a JavaScript there to change the value of the content type drop down based on the view you are opening the item from.

You can get the source view name from URL by parsing the 'Source' query string. Correspondingly, You will have to map the views and content types in the JavaScript.

Comment: Ok great thank you, i really dont know much/any javascript could you or anyone else advise where to begin with doing something like this?

Comment: You can find a similar script here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/569232ee-2c95-4d5d-8a11-7e9faa650533/how-to-hide-the-content-type-field How to parse query string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907482/how-to-get-the-query-string-by-javascript

Comment: Hi sorry, im struggling with this as imreally not clued up on javascript enough to understand what each function does. do you have any more information?